# Access to array list many times

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have list (array list)that can contain many instances (between 500-3000 instances ).
during the program some function need to **access to this list** (many times)and search for specific instance or more ,to get the instance\s they need loop on the list and provide parentName and name (which is string) and are not uniqe key .

my question is since the list need to be accessed many time there is a way to define/design it better **that the access to the list can be more efficient?**

Please keep in mind that the functions that need to get instance/s from the list
cannot provide full key the can provide only **name** and **parentName** which can have **more** that one instance.

```
List<Obj>   myList = new ArrayList<Obj>();

class obj
{
parentName
Name
type 
curr
....
```

Comment: So you should work with a map, in which each key contains a list of values. You might get a better answer if you show some more code, e.g. some example values and a snippet showing how you access the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Map<MyEntry, List<Obj>>` where `MyEntry` is a class enclosing parent name and name as such:

```
public final class MyEntry
{
    private final String parentName;
    private final String name;
    private final int hashCode;

    public MyEntry(final String parentName, final String name)
    {
        this.parentName = parentName;
        this.name = name;
        hashCode = 31 * parentName.hashCode() + name.hashCode();
    }

    // Override .equals() and .hashCode()
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        final MyEntry other = (MyEntry) o;
        return parentName.equals(other.parentName)
            && name.equals(other.name);
    }

    // Have a nice string representation
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "parent name: " + parentName + ", name: " + name;
    }
}
```

You can, for instance, have a method in your `Obj` which returns the matching `MyEntry` object. Also, if you use Guava, have a look at `MultiMap`.

You will notice that the hash code is precomputed: this can be done since the `MyEntry` class is immutable. This allows for very fast usage as keys for a `Map`.

(edit: added `.toString()`)

Comment: Hi Fge,let me see if i got u right .you are telling me to create new class which will contain key for e.g. parent name 1 name 2 and in the list they have 10 instances  the entry will be 1 & 2 and they map to list with 10 instances and etc?

Comment: @BorisMandovskes: yes, exactly. Your map will have entries like `("foo", "bar") -> [ obj1, obj2, etc]` where `obj1` and others will have `"foo"` as parent name and `"bar"` as name. Also note that it would be a good idea to override `toString()` in `MyEntry`, but that is up to you.

Comment: Hi Fge thanks for your answer,can you just explain briefly what is the purpose of the hash and equals. thanks!!!

Comment: @BorisMandovskes: the key set of a `Map` is a `Set`. Unlike a `List`, elements in `Set` are unique. You will notice that the `.add()` method of `Set` returns a boolean, which is true if and only if the set was modified as the result of the operation. In order to detect that elements are equal, implementations first check the hash code, and if an element has the same hash code of elements already present in the set, only then they use `.equals()`. As the `MyEntry` class as designed is immutable, we can calculate the hash code beforehand and make the operation all the faster.

Comment: Hi again one last question :),since i use it like <key,list<obj>> why dont use hashMap ? Thanks!!!

Comment: `HashMap` is an implementation of `Map`, that is why.

Comment: yes i know that but from performance perspective the access is faster (and this is the most important thing in the list since we have lot of access to it ) ,correct me if I wrong . ,thanks!

Comment: No, it is not any faster, the compile process ensures this. In all events, it is better to access it via the interface because, if for instance you find a faster `Map` implementation, you just have to change the concrete implementation from `HashMap` to something else without changing the rest of the code.